# Finding thickness between two points based on meeting conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a list of surfaces and depths. Some of the surfaces are labeled with the suffix _top and _base.

How can I write a function that will create a column that calculates the thickness of only the surfaces that have the same name with the _top and _base suffix (e.g. red_top - red_base = thickness)?

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Surface': ['red_top', 'red_base',
                            'blue_top', 'blue_base', 'green_top', 'pink'],
                 'Depth':[2, 6, 12, 45, 55, 145]})
```

I've tried to split the surface column to create one for the surfaces and one for the top/base, but I'm not sure if that is necessary and am still stuck on how to calculate the thickness based on meeting those conditions.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would first split "Surface" column into two parts - "color" and "level", then pivot the table by "color", and then calculate thickness as follows

```
split = df.Surface.str.split("_", expand=True)
split.columns = ["Color", "Level"]

df = pd.concat([df, split], axis=1)

df_pivoted = df.pivot(index="Color", columns="Level", values="Depth")
df_pivoted["Thinkness"] = df_pivoted.base - df_pivoted.top
```

df_pivoted for your example looks like this -

```
Level   NaN     base    top Thinkness
Color               
blue    NaN     45.0    12.0    33.0
green   NaN     NaN     55.0    NaN
pink    145.0   NaN     NaN     NaN
red     NaN     6.0     2.0     4.0
```

The NaN column has non-empty values for Surfaces without the subscript.

The line below provides thickness calculation just for data with both _top and _base,

```
thickness = (df_pivoted.base-df_pivoted.top).dropna()
print(thickness)
```

results in

```
Color
blue    33.0
red      4.0
dtype: float64
```